# Class/member function error

Tags: c++, class, member-functions

I have this snippet of code here:

```
class physics_vector
{ 
public:
    double direction, magnitude;
    int dir_mag(double dir, double mag) :direction(dir), 
        magnitude(dir) {return 0; };
};

int dir_mag(double dir, double mag)
{
    cout << "Direction: " << dir << '\n';
    cout << "Magnitude: " << mag << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to compile I get the error,

```
13:39: error: only constructors take member initializers
```

Any help please?

Comment: The error is extremely clear. You are using an initializer list (the thing that starts with a colon) on something that is *not* a constructor. Also, why do you have a method called dir_mag and a free function called dir_mag ?

Comment: @Borgleader, why initializer list is not allowed except constructor? I know i am late to ask, but i am afraid to open a new thread for same solution.

Comment: because The International Standard (god save the committee) says so

Answer (score 6):

This function:

```
int dir_mag(double dir, double mag) :direction(dir), magnitude(dir)
{return 0; };
```

is using an initializer list (`:direction(dir), magnitude(dir)`) and that's only allowed for constructors. If you had planned to make this a constructor your class should look like this:

```
class physics_vector
{ 
public:
    double direction, magnitude;
    physics_vector(double dir, double mag) :direction(dir), 
        magnitude(dir) {};
};
```

And that will  compile. Note that you are not allowed a return value from a constructor, nor do they have return types.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use initializer list in functions.Its not a valid operation in C++. You can use Initializer list only with Constructor. 
Compiler is giving very clear error.